How can I solve dimensional of time series problem in TensorFlow?
I am trying to train a Feed Forward NN but when I fit the model then says "None values not supported", I already check data and not have NaN or Null, my timeseries is a Stock timeseries so dont have any other dimension than price.
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])

Stock_AMZN_PRCL_Train = Stock_AMZN_PRCL_Train.values.reshape(-1, 1)

model.fit(Stock_AMZN_PRCL_Train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

I am expecting to fit my model
